# ora-01427 single-row subquery returns error in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set as follows:

```
ID  keyword1
1   abc
2   abc1
1   xyz
3   hjh
3   pou
```

I want the output as follows:

```
ID  keyword1  keyword2
1   abc       xyz
2   abc1
3   hjh       pou
```

the condition is: if there are more than 1 rows for a particular ID, then i should get another column of keyword in the same ID row. If no matching rows, then it should be null.

i am using the below query:

```
select c.ID,
    (select KEYWORD from table1 a where a.ECF_RULE_ID=c.ECF_RULE_ID) as  KEYWORD1,
    (select KEYWORD from table2 b where b.ECF_RULE_ID=c.ECF_RULE_ID) as KEYWORD2
from table3 c
```

but i am getting the error as:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Skip the subqueries, do LEFT JOIN's instead.

Comment: Your query includes 3 tables, but there's only sample data for one table (or?) - what about the other two?

Comment: Your query is as below? 

select c.ID,
       (select KEYWORD from table a where a.ECF_RULE_ID=c.ECF_RULE_ID) as  KEYWORD1,
       (select KEYWORD from table b where b.ECF_RULE_ID=c.ECF_RULE_ID) as KEYWORD2
from table c

Answer (score 0):

Looks you need something like;

```
select
c.ID,
a.keyword as KEYWORD1,
b.keyword as KEYWORD2

from
table3 c
LEFT JOIN table1 a ON a.ECF_RULE_ID=c.ECF_RULE_ID
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON b.ECF_RULE_ID=c.ECF_RULE_ID
```

Please look into joins, it's very powerfull.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2 value by ID, may be you can try another way, using "analytic windows function" like rank

```
select
    ECF_RULE_ID as ID,
    KEYWORD,
    rank() over (partition by ECF_RULE_ID order by KEYWORD ) as POSITION
from
    table1
```

result :

```
ID  KEYWORD  POSITION
1   abc      1
1   xyz      2
2   abc1     1
3   hjh      1
3   pou      2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use correlated query to return your desired result which can be obtained as below.

```
SELECT id
    ,keyword1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN keyword2 <> keyword1
            THEN keyword2
        ELSE NULL
        END AS keyword2
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.id
        ,(
            SELECT min(keyword)
            FROM t1 a
            WHERE a.ID = c.ID
            ) AS Keyword1
        ,(
            SELECT max(keyword)
            FROM t1 b
            WHERE b.ID = c.ID
            ) AS Keyword2
    FROM t1 c
    ) t
order by id;
```

what the above query does is that the inner correlated queries return corresponding `min` and `max` values in separate columns, `distinct` remove duplicates and `case` forces `keyword2` values to `NULL` if it matches `keyword1` values.

**Result:**

```
id  keyword1    keyword2
------------------------
1   abc         xyz
2   abc1        
3   hjh         pou
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/JOOTH54068)**

---

**Update 1:**

You can also use `left join` as below to obtain your desired result.

```
SELECT id
    ,keyword1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN keyword2 <> keyword1
            THEN keyword2
        ELSE NULL
        END AS keyword2
FROM (
    SELECT a.id
        ,max(a.keyword) AS keyword1
        ,min(b.keyword) AS keyword2
    FROM t1 a
    LEFT JOIN t1 b ON a.id = b.id
    GROUP BY a.id
    ) t
ORDER BY id;
```

**Result:**

```
id  keyword1    keyword2
------------------------
1   abc         xyz
2   abc1        
3   hjh         pou
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JVD22012)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped.

Comment: Kindly read what to do if [**answer is helpful**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :-)